# Dynamic SQL Error - Set value to a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic sql.

```
declare @CustomerId int
set @CustomerId = 1
declare @SDate datetime 
set @SDate = '2015/12/07'
declare @ItemId int
set @ItemId = 2

declare @QtyS nvarchar(max)
declare @QtyOut decimal(18,3)

set @QtyS = 'SELECT isnull(sum(d.Qty),0)
FROM InvoiceDetail AS d INNER JOIN
InvoiceHeader AS h ON d.InvoiceNo = h.InvoiceNo
where
h.CustomerId = '''+@CustomerId+''' and
d.itemmasterid = '''+@ItemId+''' and
h.Deleted = 0 and
h.invoicedate = '''+@SDate+''''

exec sp_executesql @QtyS, N'@Qty decimal(18,3) out', @QtyOut out
select @QtyOut
```

when executing this attached error coming.
Error as a text also attached with this.
Any idea?

```
Error:
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure rpt_SpecialLaunch, Line 76
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT isnull(sum(d.Qty),0)
    FROM InvoiceDetail AS d INNER JOIN
    InvoiceHeader AS h ON d.InvoiceNo = h.InvoiceNo
    where
    h.CustomerId = '' to data type int.
```

[image]

Comment: Please add error as text

Comment: Convert the non-string variables to strings before concatenating: `'xxx' + cast(@CustomerId as varchar(16)) + ' xxx'`  -  What you have can be executed in-line FYI.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
      @CustomerId INT = 1
    , @ItemId INT = 2
    , @SDate DATETIME = '2015/12/07'
    , @QtyS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @QtyOut DECIMAL(18,3)

SET @QtyS = '
SELECT @QtyOut = SUM(d.Qty)
FROM dbo.InvoiceDetail d
JOIN dbo.InvoiceHeader h ON d.InvoiceNo = h.InvoiceNo
WHERE h.CustomerId = @CustomerId
    AND d.itemmasterid = @ItemId
    AND h.Deleted = 0
    AND h.invoicedate = @SDate'

EXEC sp_executesql @QtyS,
                   N'@CustomerId INT, @ItemId INT, @SDate DATETIME, @QtyOut decimal(18,3) out',
                   @CustomerId = @CustomerId, @ItemId = @ItemId, @SDate = @SDate, @QtyOut = @QtyOut OUT

SELECT @QtyOut
```

> Must declare the scalar variable "@QtyS"

```
DECLARE
      @CustomerId INT = 1
    , @ItemId INT = 2
    , @SDate DATETIME = '2015/12/07'
    , @QtyS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @QtyOut DECIMAL(18,3)

SET @QtyS = '
SELECT @QtyOut = 1
SELECT @CustomerId, @ItemId, @SDate'

EXEC sp_executesql @QtyS,
                   N'@CustomerId INT, @ItemId INT, @SDate DATETIME, @QtyOut decimal(18,3) out',
                   @CustomerId = @CustomerId, @ItemId = @ItemId, @SDate = @SDate, @QtyOut = @QtyOut OUT

SELECT @QtyOut
```

2005:

```
DECLARE
      @CustomerId INT
    , @ItemId INT
    , @SDate DATETIME
    , @QtyS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @QtyOut DECIMAL(18,3)

SELECT
      @CustomerId = 1
    , @ItemId = 2
    , @SDate = '2015/12/07'

SET @QtyS = '
SELECT @QtyOut = SUM(d.Qty)
FROM dbo.InvoiceDetail d
JOIN dbo.InvoiceHeader h ON d.InvoiceNo = h.InvoiceNo
WHERE h.CustomerId = @CustomerId
    AND d.itemmasterid = @ItemId
    AND h.Deleted = 0
    AND h.invoicedate = @SDate'

EXEC sp_executesql @QtyS,
                   N'@CustomerId INT, @ItemId INT, @SDate DATETIME, @QtyOut DECIMAL(18,3) OUT',
                   @CustomerId = @CustomerId, @ItemId = @ItemId, @SDate = @SDate, @QtyOut = @QtyOut OUT

SELECT @QtyOut
```

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@QtyS".

Comment: Command(s) completed successfully... don't have any issues in syntax

Comment: select @@version ? just provide a results and i will check

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64)   Dec 10 2010 10:38:40   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: you tagged question with 2008 ;) ok... 5 min

Comment: check the last query and read this - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/03/18/sql-server-2008-2011-declare-and-assign-variable-in-single-statement/